# Выбор активного значения из Option

Tags: html, sql, laravel

Делаю магазин одежды, где случился ступор на моменте выбора активного значения из option.
Имеется следующий код, где выводится информация из таблицы размеров, которая связанна с основной таблицей товаров по id:

```html
<select>
       @foreach($productsSize as $size)
       <option name="size" value="{{$size->id}}"> {{$size->size}}</option>
       @endforeach
</select>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код из контроллера:

```html
$productsSize = ProductsSize::query()->where(['product_id'=>$Request->id])->get();
```

Так вот, каким образом взять значение из выбранного option?

Comment: где то у вас надо полагать имеется значение текущего выбранного, или что?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял, то надо следующее:

```html
<select name="size">
    @foreach($productsSize as $size)
        <option value="{{$size->id}}"> {{$size->size}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

А в контроллере для получения соответственно:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $size = $request->input('size');
}
```

Comment: Сделал как вы написали, но увы $size выдаёт null

Comment: А не из-за ли что отсутствует form?

Comment: Да, информацимая из select'а должна попадать в запрос: либо если в форме с этим select'ом нажать на кнопку submit; либо через ajax.